# nested loop through xml-nodes using powershell

Tags: xml, powershell

I would like to extract from a xml-file the value of the name-attributes from all window- and all viewpoint-nodes.

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8' ?>
        <workbook>
            <windows>
                <window class='dashboard' name='D1'>
                  <viewpoints>
                    <viewpoint name='V1'> </viewpoint>
                    <viewpoint name='V2'> </viewpoint>
                    <viewpoint name='V3'> </viewpoint>
                </viewpoints>
                </window>
                <window class='dashboard' name='D2'>
                  <viewpoints>
                    <viewpoint name='V10'> </viewpoint>
                    <viewpoint name='V11'> </viewpoint>
                  </viewpoints>
                 </window>
            </windows>
        </workbook>
```

This is the code I have written:

```
[XML]$doc = get-content -path 'W:\Demo1.xml'


$objs = @()
$dashboards = $doc.SelectNodes("//window[@class = 'dashboard']")

foreach ($dashboard in $dashboards)
{
   $worksheets = $dashboard.SelectNodes("//viewpoint[@name]")

    foreach ($worksheet in $worksheets)
    {
        $obj = new-object psobject -prop @{Dashboard=$dashboard.name; Worksheet = $worksheet.name}; 
        $objs += $obj;

    }  
 } 

$objs
```

---

**What I expected:**

```
dashboard   worksheet   
D1          V1
D1          V2
D1          V3
D2          V10
D2          V11
```

**What I got:**

```
dashboard   worksheet   
D1          V1
D1          V2
D1          V3
D1          V10
D1          V11
D1          V14
D2          V1
D2          V2
D2          V3
D2          V10
D2          V11
D2          V14
```

What is wrong here? The result is completely contradictory to my understanding of how a nested loop works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An XPath starting with a `/` character means that it will be begin at the document root node. To create a relative XPath from the context node, you need to put a `.` before the `/`.

So your code should be:

```
[XML]$doc = get-content -path 'W:\Demo1.xml'


$objs = @()
$dashboards = $doc.SelectNodes("//window[@class = 'dashboard']")

foreach ($dashboard in $dashboards)
{
   $worksheets = $dashboard.SelectNodes(".//viewpoint[@name]")

    foreach ($worksheet in $worksheets)
    {
        $obj = new-object psobject -prop @{Dashboard=$dashboard.name; Worksheet = $worksheet.name}; 
        $objs += $obj;

    }  
 } 

$objs
```

Comment: You saved my day. Thank you. I spend hours to find the error and it's only a little dot missing......

Answer (score 1):

You could also simplify that and adopt your `xpath` to select all `viewpoint` nodes from dashboard window:

```
[XML]$doc = get-content -path 'W:\Demo1.xml'

$objs = @()
$worksheets = $doc.SelectNodes("//window[@class = 'dashboard']//viewpoint[@name]")

foreach ($worksheet in $worksheets)
{
    $obj = new-object psobject -prop @{Dashboard=$worksheet.ParentNode.ParentNode.name; Worksheet = $worksheet.name}; 
    $objs += $obj;
}  

$objs
```

And here a solution without `xpath`:

```
[XML]$doc = get-content -path 'W:\Demo1.xml'

$objs = $doc.DocumentElement.windows.window | Where class -eq 'dashboard' | foreach {
    $dashboardName = $_.name
    $_.viewpoints.viewpoint | foreach {
        new-object psobject -prop @{Dashboard=$dashboardName; Worksheet = $_.name}
    }
}
```

Comment: Upps, you are right - I fixed my answer (now using `ParentNode` properties to get the dashboard). I will also provide you an example without xpath in a min.

Comment: Hmm, the line    $worksheets = $doc.SelectNodes("//window[@class = 'dashboard']//viewpoint[@name]") produces an error. (translated from german: it's not possible, to invoke a method for an expression having the value NULL)

Comment: @jisaak: thank you for your second piece of code. I just tried it out. For whatever reason it returns nothing. :-(

Comment: I omit the `$objs` that prints the result, I only assign the result to it. Just write `$objs` in the last line and you will see the output.